# Why is the result string returns only last result value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dictionary, foreach

I have a code which takes some values from input fields the user inputs. My JS code is supposed to check whether all required titles are not empty. If not, it should display `alert` message with the result. Here's my code

```js
var result = "";
function isStringEmpty(string2Check) 
{
    return string2Check == "" || string2Check[0] == " ";
};
var titles = 
[
    ["1", "This is 1st title(not empty)"],
    ["", "Suppose this is empty"],
    ["", "Suppose this is empty too"]
];
    
var titlesMap = new Map(titles);

titlesMap.forEach(function(key, value, titlesMap) 
{
    if(isStringEmpty(value)) 
    {
        result += 'Field ' + '"' + key + '"' +' cannot be empty!\n'
    }
});
result = result.replace(/\n$/, "");
alert(result);
```

See? The "Suppose this is empty" is ignored(the result string doesn't contain it) :( and the `result` only takes the last result message. Why? BTW, why are the `key` and the `value` properties in the map are messed up?(I thought that key is "1" and value is "This is 1st title(not empty)", but it's not..) I guess that this is because of using arrays as properties...

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code with the debugger built into your browser? Debugging is the *first* step in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Field "Suppose this is empty" cannot be empty!
Field "Suppose this is empty too" cannot be empty!

Comment: Key should be unique

Comment: `console.log(titlesMap)`, you will get your answer

Comment: @AswinRamesh: Yes, but there's no need to stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch when you can *turn on the lights* using the debugger. :-)

Comment: yes you are right @T.J.Crowder anything will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a `Map` and passing it key/value pairs. Keys in a map must be unique. By adding an entry with the same key (`""`) twice, you're *overwriting* the first one with the second.

If you don't mean those as key/value pairs, don't use `Map`, just use the array of arrays directly, like this (main changes are to remove `titlesMap` and within the `forEach`):

```js
var result = "";
function isStringEmpty(string2Check) 
{
    return string2Check == "" || string2Check[0] == " ";
};
var titles = 
[
    ["1", "This is 1st title(not empty)"],
    ["", "Suppose this is empty"],
    ["", "Suppose this is empty too"]
];

titles.forEach(function(entry) 
{
    if(isStringEmpty(entry[0])) 
    {
        result += 'Field ' + '"' + entry[1] + '"' +' cannot be empty!\n'
    }
});
result = result.replace(/\n$/, "");
alert(result);
```

---

Side note: Your `isStringEmpty` function will say that `" foo"` is empty. I assume that isn't what you want to do. You probably just want:

```
function isStringEmpty(string2Check) {
    return !string2Check.trim();
}
```

...polyfilling [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) for obsolete browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Well, no, actually ` foo` is considered as an empty, since it starts with a space. But don't edit it, it will be helpful anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you see your two values are empty

```
var titles = 
[
    ["1", "This is 1st title(not empty)"],
    ["", "Suppose this is empty"],
    ["", "Suppose this is empty too"]
];
```

when you are mapping then on mapping time key should be unique.

```
var titlesMap = new Map(titles);
```

First Time when it maps then value will be

```
["", "Suppose this is empty"]
```

here key is ===> **""** and value will be **Suppose this is empty**

but after then it overwrites the value of the key

```
["", "Suppose this is empty too"]
```

So the last value will be in **Suppose this is empty too**

You should try without mapping